# NServiceBus Saga can't find handler because it's using the wrong ID

Tags: handler, message, saga, nservicebus4

I am using NSB 4.  I have a saga that has the following

```
BaseSaga<OrderSagaData>,
IAmStartedByMessages<OrderMessage>,
IHandleMessages<VendorCreatedMessage>, ....
```

BasSaga just wraps saga. I don't know why I've got bigger fish to fry right now.

I then have

```
public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
{
     ConfigureMapping<VendorCreatedMessage>(m => m.SagaId).ToSaga(s => s.Id);
```

my OrderSagaData looks like this

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderSagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    [Unique]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid MessageId { get; set; }
```

VendorCreatedMessage

```
[Serializable]
public class VendorCreatedMessage 
{
    public Guid SagaId { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
```

Then finally in my logs I get

Could not find a saga for the message type Messages.Vendors.VendorCreatedMessage with id 7af7dff2-bf03-4ebd-9e6c-a27a01125ceb. Going to invoke SagaNotFoundHandlers.

The message is the correct namespace and all, but the id (7af7) is not only the wrong id but I can't find it anywhere else.  It's not in the vendor service logs or in the saga logs.  When I look at the queue the vendor service is sending the correct SagaId.

I'm very confused and don't know where it's getting strange (7af7) id or why it's not using the proper sagaid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your `VendorCreatedMessage` missing the `IContainSagaData` marker interface inheritance?

Comment: @SeanFarmar Hi, the VendroCreatedMessage is not actually the sagadata class.  It's just a return message from a service that creates the vendor and then alerts the saga that it's done.  Should the message also implement IContainSagaData?

Comment: No, sorry, i miss read this

Comment: The Id is a transport message Id, so that might explain why you can find the message, was the saga started already at the time the `VendorCreatedMessage` was handled?

Comment: yes, the initial message is received, I put the values from the origional message on teh sagadata class then I create teh createvendormessage and send it to the createvendor queue.  the create vendor service then does it's thing and returns to the saga.

Comment: Any chance you can put the actual code or a code that reproduces the issue in github/zip/drop box?